# How to use a disk amoung two VM instances in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to configure one instance, and be able to create other instances with this setup (or eventually have a load balancer do it). From what I understand, to do this I have to create an Image from a Disk.

So I do the following: Side menu -> Compute Engine -> Disks and create a 10GB disk and name it DISK01

Then I create a new VM instance and attach this disk onto that instance (instead of creating a new disk which is the default). I SSH into the instance and install all the software I want the instance(s) to have.

If I create another VM instance and also attach DISK01, what's the expected behavior? Will both instances be able to access the *same* disk, or is a copy made for the new instance?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should check out [the section on Persistent Disks](https://cloud.google.com/persistent-disk/) - it claims that you can mount a disk on multiple VMs:

> Persistent Disk offer unique multi-reader capability. With
>   multi-reader mounting, many virtual machines can read data from a
>   single Persistent Disk with no performance degradation. Multi-reader
>   mounting makes sharing content a snap.